# While loop cp give copies of partial file (linux)

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, filesystems

I am trying to copy a list of file in varying directories based on their sample name using the following script. Although the files are copied, the file are only partially copied. I have 64k lines in each file, but only exactly 40k lines are copied.

```
while read sample
do
echo copying ${sample}
cp ${sample_dir}/*${sample}*/file.tsv ${output_dir}/${sample}.file.tsv
done < ${input_list}/sample_list.txt
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Does the cp command have limits on how many lines it can copy?

Cheers,

Comment: Even if there are multiple matches, that shouldn't cause a partial copy; you should just get an error about the destination not being a directory.

Comment: I should add that I do not get any errors, i only noticed that it wasn't a compete copy when I realized I was missing some information. There should be no multiple matches and it should have been a simple copying task.

Comment: Is `${sample_dir}/*${sample}*/file.tsv` giving exactly one file?

Comment: Try `echo "cp ${sample_dir}/*${sample}*/file.tsv ${output_dir}/${sample}.file.tsv"`, copy and paste the resulting line and see if you have a problem without the while loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Water A. Everything looks fine here. I get the correct file name input and the new file name output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think CP command has limit on file size (unless ulimit has restrictions) to copy but it has limit on number of files to copy or check if it is related to new file creation with larger size.

check limits across the system using command ulimit,

```
ulimit -a
```

And verify the file size is not limited to 40k and if it is unlimited then no issue (like, file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited).

Try with rsync command if it works for you,

```
rsync -avh source destination
```

Could you verify few things,

1) Verify if it's not file read error, like cat the file and save the output to another file (either manually/redirect).

```
cat *.tsv > /tmp/verify-size
```

And then verify the size on that file,

```
du -h /tmp/verify-size ---> This should be 64k
```

2) Create large dummy file with size > 40k (or exact size of .tsv (64k))

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/verify-newfile-size bs=64000 count=1

du -h /tmp/verify-newfile-size  ---> This should be 64k
```

If this new file creation success (if you are able to create a file with any size) then try CP command and verify the size

-OR- Try with dd command

```
dd if=/tmp/verify-newfile-size of=/tmp/verify-newfile-size2 bs=64000 count=1
```

3) Try with an atomic command,

```
mv /tmp/verify-newfile-size /tmp/verify-newfile-size3
```

Comment: Thanks Balaji! rsync seemed to have worked for me. Cheers!